# Including Data (.json) FIles with cmake C++

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and am coding in C++. My code reads from a .json file at some point, but receives an error stating that the file cannot be found. I'm assuming this is because cmake is unable to find the file.
The .json is in a subdirectory of the directory that the cmake file is in. I have seen a lot of solutions regarding inclusion of source files with relative paths, but one regarding non-source files.

How would I go about including my data files using cmake and a relative path? Thanks in advance!

**edit:** I apologize for not including more information initially! The directory structure looks like this:

- project dir

  - sub dir 1

    - CMakeList.txt **A**
    - sub dir 2

      - CMakeList.txt **B**
      - .cpp source files that read from the .JSON files
      - sub dir containing .JSON files

        - .JSON files being referenced

There are 2 CMakeList.txt files in different directories and the sub directory containing the .JSON files I want to use in my C++ code is in the lowest-level directory.

Currently, CMakeList.txt B uses:
`add_executable(execName ${SOURCE_FILES})`
to generate the executable. 
I have tried modifying that line to be:
`add_executable(execName ${RELATIVE_PATH_TO_JSON_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})`
, but unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: If you use `install()` command in cmake, please provide your `CMakeLists.txt`. If you use `execute_process()`/`exec_program()` in cmake, please make sure you specify a correct working directory. Otherwise your problem is not cmake-related. Please provide the output of `GetFullPathName()` for your file in the code, as well as the actual absolute location of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
I have added some more information to the original post if that helps... I don't think I am using install() or execute_process()/exec_program() at all. But, I am also very new to CMake and have had little exposure to it at all. Does the provided directory structure make the question a little more clear?

Comment: CMake is not that kind of build system that creates the full working environment for your program to run. When you start your compiled program, the directory you are currently in (which could be a different directory from where the program binary is located) becomes your program's working directory, and all the relative paths that your program uses are resolved from there. That's why I was asking for `GetFullPathName()` output.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick hack you can add

```
add_definitions("-DPATH_TO_JSON=\"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/json.txt\")
```

to your CMakeLists.txt. After that you can use `PATH_TO_JSON` define in your C++ code.

If you want your app to be able to access the file after installation, you should operate on `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` instead of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`.

Answer (score -1):

`include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/json)`

Comment: A description to this line of code would be definitely helpful!